# Android marketplace with PayPal support

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

Are there any Android market alternative that support PayPal payment?

Answer (score 6):

[SlideMe](http://slideme.org/) supports paypal. but i dont know what their "inventory" looks like compared to android market. You could try to get the PayPal debit card and link that to a google checkout account, if you can...

Answer (score 3):

[AndAppStore](http://andappstore.com/), but it doesn't offer anywhere near the number of apps as Google's market.